# Calculate difference in months between two dates in Unix?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, unix-timestamp

I have two variables in the format 'YYYYMM'

```
DATE1=201712
DATE2=201801
```

How do I calculate the difference between these two date variables in months in unix?

Comment: what is you expected output for the input provided? 1?

Comment: @Allan ,The resultant variable should have the value as 1. i.e. RESULT=1. As the difference is of 1 month between DATE1 and DATE2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE1=201712
DATE2=201801

y1=${DATE1:0:4}
m1=${DATE1:4:2}

y2=${DATE2:0:4}
m2=${DATE2:4:2}

diff=$(( ($y2 - $y1) * 12 + (10#$m2 - 10#$m1) ))
echo $diff
```

Comment: The above is failing when DATE1=201709 and DATE2=201802

Comment: I changed ($m2 - $m1) to (10#$m2 - 10#$m1). Now it works

Answer (score 4):

I have prepared the following bash function for you let me know if it is clear:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DATE1=201712
DATE2=201801

function dateDiffMonth() {
    local y1=$(date -d "$1""01" '+%Y') # extract the year from your date1
    local y2=$(date -d "$2""01" '+%Y') # extract the year from your date2
    local m1=$(date -d "$1""01" '+%m') # extract the month from your date1
    local m2=$(date -d "$2""01" '+%m') # extract the month from your date2
    echo $(( ($y2 - $y1) * 12 + (10#$m2 - 10#$m1) )) #compute the months difference 12*year diff+ months diff -> 10# force the shell to interpret the following number in base-10
}

RESULT=`dateDiffMonth $DATE1 $DATE2`
echo "there is a gap of $RESULT months betwen $DATE2 and $DATE1"
```

Comment: The above is failing when DATE1=201709 and DATE2=201802

Comment: Nice pick I have updated the code and fixed the issue! The problem was the leading `0` in the months that would induce the shell into interpreting it as **octal numbers**...

Comment: You can also use date +"%-m" and +"%-Y" to tell date to not pad the numeric value with zeroes. (source: man date)